# bluetooth module with stk500_recv() error

Tags: serial, bluetooth, softwareserial

I am trying to dow what is demonstrated in this [tutorial](http://www.instructables.com/id/Voice-Activated-Arduino-Bluetooth-Android/?ALLSTEPS). I have altered the original setup a little by adding a level converter to not fry the Bluetooth module and resistors for the LEDs, as well as using only 2 instead of four LEDs (which I adjusted for in code later). other than that I am using the exact same setup, code,and procedure. Yet when I try to run my code on the Arduino. I get the error below. I believe it is due to using Tx/Rx and serial at the same time but I really don't know anything about this. Should I add more libraries?
Should I change the wiring shown in the tutorial link? It seems like I need to use Tx/Rx

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xce
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xce
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
```

Here is the code I used from tutorial:

```c
//Coded By: Angelo Casimiro (4/27/14)
//Voice Activated Arduino (Bluetooth + Android)
//Feel free to modify it but remember to give credit

String voice;
int
led1 = 2, //Connect LED 1 To Pin #2
led2 = 3, //Connect LED 2 To Pin #3
led3 = 4, //Connect LED 3 To Pin #4
led4 = 5, //Connect LED 4 To Pin #5
led5 = 6; //Connect LED 5 To Pin #6
//--------------------------Call A Function-------------------------------// 
void allon(){
     digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
     digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
     digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
     digitalWrite(led4, HIGH);
     digitalWrite(led5, HIGH);
}
void alloff(){
     digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
     digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
     digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
     digitalWrite(led4, LOW);
     digitalWrite(led5, LOW);
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------// 
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led5, OUTPUT);
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------// 
void loop() {
  while (Serial.available()){  //Check if there is an available byte to read
  delay(10); //Delay added to make thing stable
  char c = Serial.read(); //Conduct a serial read
  if (c == '#') {break;} //Exit the loop when the # is detected after the word
  voice += c; //Shorthand for voice = voice + c
  } 
  if (voice.length() > 0) {
    Serial.println(voice);
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------//   
  //----------Control Multiple Pins/ LEDs----------// 
       if(voice == "*all on") {allon();}  //Turn Off All Pins (Call Function)
  else if(voice == "*all off"){alloff();} //Turn On  All Pins (Call Function)

  //----------Turn On One-By-One----------//
  else if(voice == "*TV on") {digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);}
  else if(voice == "*fan on") {digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);}
  else if(voice == "*computer on") {digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);}
  else if(voice == "*bedroom lights on") {digitalWrite(led4, HIGH);}
  else if(voice == "*bathroom lights on") {digitalWrite(led5, HIGH);}
  //----------Turn Off One-By-One----------//
  else if(voice == "*TV off") {digitalWrite(led1, LOW);}
  else if(voice == "*fan off") {digitalWrite(led2, LOW);}
  else if(voice == "*computer off") {digitalWrite(led3, LOW);}
  else if(voice == "*bedroom lights off") {digitalWrite(led4, LOW);}
  else if(voice == "*bathroom lights off") {digitalWrite(led5, LOW);}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------// 
voice="";}} //Reset the variable after initiating
```

Comment: How did you upload the sketch? With the Bluetooth module still connected? In that case please disconnect it and the upload. Connect again after the upload.

Comment: Yes your comment was the solution Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

How did you upload the sketch? With the Bluetooth module still connected? In that case please disconnect it and the upload. Connect again after the upload.